# make with dynamic target names

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I know that I can use the automatic variable `$@` from within a target in a makefile to retrieve the name of the current target. Now I wonder whether it is possible to have a makefile that looks like this:...

```
$@:
    g++ $@ && ./a.out
```

The idea is that typing `make test.cpp` should run `g++ test.cpp && ./a.out` where as `make main.cpp` should run `g++ main.cpp && ./a.out`.

I see that wildcards might be strongly related to my problem. However, a makefile like this:

```
*.cpp:
    g++ $@ && ./a.out
```

does indeed create the appropriate targets, but running `make test.cpp` with such a makefile yields `make: >>test.cpp<< is already up-to-date` - without the compilation taking place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behavior you described is the behavior you want from the make system and this is why it is so loved by many and scales so well.

`make test.cpp` does not work because what you want is `make a.out`

Try starting from a simple but correct [makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2908351/267482) and evolve it to your needs

To trigger the compilation remove `test.o` and say `make test.o`, or say `touch test.cpp` and then again `make test.o`. If you do not want intermediate object files (I tell you - you do want them) you can apply the above advice replacing `test.o` with `a.out`.

You are trying to *push* where you should be *pulling* :-)

As @MadScientist reminded in his comment, one of useful features of GNU Make is a vast set of default rules which may save quite a bit of boilerplate when you don't need fine control of each step.

Comment: To be fully complete this answer should point out that make has a set of built-in _implicit rules_ that lets it understand how to build a `.o` from a `.c` file, as well as various other types of source files.  Further, you can define your own implicit rules or override the built-in ones if they don't do what you need.  Standard make supports _suffix rules_ which are a limited form of implicit rule, and GNU make supports _pattern rules_ which are a more powerful form.  You can look up these terms with Google to learn about them and how to specify them.

Comment: @MadScientist - I agree that automatic rules are useful to certain degree, but when building anything simpler than a test app you better have a full control

Comment: Using implicit rules in no way cedes any control over anything.  And, in any build system simpler than a test app they are absolutely CRUCIAL to avoid lots of wasteful redundancy.  Some people prefer static pattern rules, but I don't see any big advantage personally.

Comment: @MadScientist - I added a note on default rules, I have even found a sample makefile in one of my old projects (link in the answer).

Comment: Maybe when you said "automatic rules" you mean the default or built-in implicit rules, and not implicit rules in general?  It's true that the built-in rules sometimes won't do what you want, which is why you can (and perhaps should) redefine them.  However, they are nicely variable-ized so very often all you need to do is set `CC`, `CFLAGS`, `CXX`, `CXXFLAGS`, `CPPFLAGS`, etc. and everything will work quite well.

Comment: @MadScientist - have a look here http://bobah.net/d4d/source-code/misc/cpp-dependency-injection, precisely what you've just said

Comment: Thank you and sorry for the late response :)

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar need when trying to make Go program. I solved my problem by setting the target to `*`.

In addition, you need to pass the `.PHONY` directive to filter out the files you want to process, otherwise something like `make: 'clock1' is up to date`, because my makefile already has clock1's folder in its directory.

```
GO_BUILD = go build
GO_BIN ?= $(shell go env GOPATH)/bin
PROG = $(GO_BIN)/$@

*:
    $(GO_BUILD) -o $(PROG) ./$@/*.go
    ls -al $(PROG)
test:
    @echo ${GO_BIN}

.PHONY: clock1 clock2 countdown*
```

RUN make command:

```
$ make clock1   
go build -o /data/go/bin/clock1 ./clock1/*.go
ls -al /data/go/bin/clock1
-rwxr-xr-x  1 Terry  staff  3013840 Sep 25 16:53 /data/go/bin/clock1

$ make clock2 
go build -o /data/go/bin/clock2 ./clock2/*.go
ls -al /data/go/bin/clock2
-rwxr-xr-x  1 Terry  staff  3177296 Sep 25 16:53 /data/go/bin/clock2

$ make countdown1
go build -o /data/go/bin/countdown1 ./countdown1/*.go
ls -al /data/go/bin/countdown1
```

Comment: its probably better to use `$*` over `$@` since `$*` will treat all args as a single string while `$@` will treat them as individual strings.

Comment: @TheFool I don't see any use of `$*` in the makefile, just `*` as a target, and again as a shell wildcard in the recipe.

Comment: @PeterWhittaker, there is multiple times $@ in the recipes. Which can have undesirable effects.

Comment: @TheFool Apologies, you are correct, I read your comment backwards somehow. Since `$@` is used multiple times, once explicitly and twice via the reference to `PROG`, would you recommend something like `*: TGT=$@` on one line, above the current `*:` rule, then using `${TGT}` and `${GO_BIN}/${TGT}` in the current rule? My thinking is that TGT would be defined once, then referenced directly to avoid issues with potential reevaluations of `$@`.