# Can make build targets for unknown pre-requisites?

Tags: makefile

I need to process all files with a particular extension, and package up the results into a single archive. Is there a way to have `make` do this?

For example suppose I need to take all the *.w* files and produce a *.n* file for each one with any vowels turned to periods, then `tar` up the results. If I create a `Makefile` as follows:

```
novowels.tar: %.n
    tar cf $@ $^

%.n: %.w
    sed -e "s/[aeiou]/./g" > $@ < $<
```

`make` (unsurprisingly) returns the following if there are no *.n* files in the directory:

```
make: *** No rule to make target '%.n', needed by 'novowels.tar'.  Stop.
```

I can call `make the.n` and it'll create the file from *the.w* (assuming that exists), and if I then call `make` it'll get included in the archive.

The question is: how (best) to have `make` realise that there are a whole load of *.w* files that need converting to *.n* files in the first place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take this as an example:

```
ALLFILES_IN  := $(wildcard *.w)
ALLFILES_OUT := $(ALLFILES_IN:.w=.n)


$(info In : $(ALLFILES_IN))
$(info Out: $(ALLFILES_OUT))

%.n: %.w 
   cat $< > $@

all.tar: $(ALLFILES_OUT)
  @echo "Tar:" $^
```

Maybe you find something like that helpful:

```
CPP_FILES := $(wildcard src/*.cpp)
OBJ_FILES := $(addprefix obj/,$(notdir $(CPP_FILES:.cpp=.o)))
```

which was stolen from:
    [Can I compile all .cpp files in src/ to .o's in obj/, then link to binary in ./?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2908057/makefiles-compile-all-cpp-files-in-src-to-os-in-obj-then-link-to-binary)

Comment: Brilliant! I knew there'd be wildcards involved, but it didn't occur to make a list of the input files then change the extensions to get the output files and make that the pre-req.