# make objects in Makefile

Tags: c++, makefile

I have the following Makefile:

```
CXX       = g++
CXXFLAGS  = -Wall -g
SOURCES  := divisor.cpp multiplier.cpp
OBJECTS  := ${SOURCES:.cpp=.o}

%.o: %.cpp 
        $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $< -o $@

%: %.o $(OBJECTS)
        $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $@.o -o $@.out

$(OBJECTS): %.o: %.cpp
        $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $< -o $@
clean:
        rm -f *.o
```

What I want this make file is the following:
If I add a source file called `123.cpp` to the working directory, I want it to generate its object file and then link the compiled sources specified in `$(SOURCES)`, this means:

```
g++ -c -Wall -g 123.cpp
g++ multipler.o divisor.o 123.o -o 123
```

If `multiplier.cpp` or `divisor.cpp` has to be generated or updated, I want make to do it.

But I'm failing, because `divisor.o` and `multiplier.o` are not automatically generated

How may I achieve this?

**Edit**

Just to clarify, there are two types of source code files in the working directory: `divisor.cpp`, `multipler.cpp` is one type, and any other file, say, `123.cpp` is the other type. In a sense, `divisor.cpp` and `multiplier.cpp` are requisites to the other source files.

I want to automate the process of compiling the prerequisites and link them when compiling the other files

```
g++ -c multiplier.cpp
g++ -c divisor.cpp
g++ -c -Wall -g 123.cpp
g++ multipler.o divisor.o 123.o -o 123
```

Comment: Firstly, you have no rule depending on ``$(SOURCES)`` in place. You need something similar to what you did with ``$(OBJECTS)``

Comment: You didn't specify any final target depending on `$(OBJECTS)`?

Comment: Does not the target `$(OBJECTS)` qualify as a rule for `$(SOURCES)` implicitly?
 
The final target depending on `$(OBJECTS)` is not `%:%.o $(OBJECTS)` ?

Thanks both

Comment: When you say "add a source file called `123.cpp`", do you mean put that file into the working directory, or add "123.cpp" to the makefile somehow?

Comment: I mean "add a source file called `123.cpp`" i will edit the question accordingly. Thanks for the remark

Comment: possible duplicate of [Makefiles - Compile all .cpp files in src/ to .o's in obj/, then link to binary in /](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2908057/makefiles-compile-all-cpp-files-in-src-to-os-in-obj-then-link-to-binary)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `wildcard` function:

```
SOURCES := $(wildcard *.cpp)
```

Then, you can remove your "special" source files:

```
SPECIAL_SOURCES := divisor.cpp multiplier.cpp
SOURCES := $(filter-out $(SPECIAL_SOURCES),$(SOURCES))
```

And change your rules to build the stuff you actually want:

```
$(SPECIAL_OBJECTS) := $(SPECIAL_SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
$(BINARIES) := $(patsubst .cpp,,$(SOURCES))

$(SPECIAL_OBJECTS) : %.o : %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o $@ $^

$(BINARIES) : % : %.cpp $(SPECIAL_OBJECTS)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $^
```

Comment: Thanks I'm trying it as soon as a I can :)