# ,Mingw cant find linked file

Tags: c++, mingw, header-files

My program is extremely simple and I'm just learning how to work with prototypes by making header files.

My folder setup is like this:

---

- **other.cpp**
- **other.h**
- **entry.cpp**

My file, `entry.cpp`, looks like this:

```
#include "other.h"
int main(){
   doSomething();
   return 0;
}
```

`doSomething` is a function declared in other.cpp and is prototyped in other.h like so:

```
//ifndefine pre-processor statements
void doSomething();
```

**Building is where I run into trouble.** Running`g++ main_c_file.cpp -o name.exe` in the console is supposed to create the executable. The problem I am having is that it doesn't know what `doSomething` is.

I suspect it's because the processor is not searching for `other.cpp`. I assumed, based on the tutorial I am following, that I didn't actually need to specify this file; it worked fairly well in their [video](https://www.udemy.com/free-learn-c-tutorial-beginners/#/lecture/1747818) to simply include just the header file and have the cpp file in the same directory.

***further:*** I downloaded their source code and the problem remained. It is not my code, it is how I am trying to build my files. I am not using an IDE to build my programs (I am using Atom IDE to write programs if you know of a shortcut through there), and like stated earlier I am just running the Mingw `g++ cppfile.cpp -o` command.

Besides the straight answer, if there is a way that can make building cpp projects easier please link me to it or write it here. I have had nothing but trouble in the past trying to learn this language.

Comment: g++ entry.cpp other.cpp -o name.exe

You have to make sure to compile your other source files, if you have them compiled then you will need to specify their object files.

Comment: Thanks for a solution! It works, but if you know of a way to simplify this, or a program that automates this I would appreciate it even more :).

Comment: If the code is in file `a/b/c/d/e/f.cpp`, and you `#include "a/b/c/d/e/f.h"` in `main.cpp`, the compiler simply won't magically search `a/b/c/d/e/f.cpp`. IDEs that provide project building capabilities sometimes hide the fact that you'd use `g++ main.cpp a/b/c/d/e/f.cpp -o my_program` on the command line to build the working program. You could look into using makefiles and download GNU Make if you don't have it already. That way, you'd need only to type `make` to create your program.

Comment: @Lemony-Andrew [makefiles?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2908057/makefiles-compile-all-cpp-files-in-src-to-os-in-obj-then-link-to-binary) Another link [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481269/how-to-make-simple-c-makefile)