# makefile to create own directory for object files not working

Tags: c++, makefile

I am new to makefiles and want to save all my object files in an own directory. I googled a lot and came to that solution:

```
CXX = clang++

# compiler flags
CXXFLAGS = -O3 -Wall -Werror -std=c++11
CFLAGS_SFML = -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system
SRCS = getInput.cpp createOutput.cpp main.cpp
OBJDIR = obj
OBJS = $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/, SRCS:.cpp=.o)

all: program.exe

program.exe: $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o program.exe $(OBJS) $(CFLAGS_SFML)

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

When I try to run the makefile I get this error:

`` makefile:12: *** target pattern contains no `%'.  Stop. ``

It seems as this error is quite common and does not tell the detail about what is wrong. It would be great if someone could help me.

Comment: Are your sources .c files or .cpp? You mention one in une place and the other a few lines below

Comment: Sorry, that was just a typo while writing the question. It's cpp

Comment: @Jonas $(XX) and $(CC) are also not defined with in this Makefile.

Comment: I should have read a few more times through my code

Comment: Try `$(OBJS): $(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SRCS)/%.cpp` instead of `$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.cpp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem with `OBJS = $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/, SRCS:.cpp=.o)`

Try this one. First you have to make the obj directory also.

```
CXX = clang++

# compiler flags
CXXFLAGS = -O3 -Wall -Werror -std=c++11
CFLAGS_SFML = -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system
SRCS = main.cpp
OBJDIR = obj
OBJS = $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/, $(SRCS:.cpp=.o))


all: program.exe

program.exe: $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o program.exe $(OBJS) $(CFLAGS_SFML)

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

For more information use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2908057/makefiles-compile-all-cpp-files-in-src-to-os-in-obj-then-link-to-binary).

Comment: Thank you, that solved my problem. great. Just one last thing, it complains the directory "obj" does not exist. So when I add it manually everything works fine. But is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: @Jonas i am not expert in makefile. You can refer to this book  http://www.oreilly.com/openbook/make3/book/index.csp. Mark as solution and upvote :P

Comment: I will suggest you to use some IDE or buil tool like CMake. Because it's better to spend time on code rather build system