# Makefile: for each .x file, create a .html file

Tags: makefile

([Similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2908057/makefiles-compile-all-cpp-files-in-src-to-os-in-obj-then-link-to-binary)). For every .x file in the directory I want to run a command to generate an HTML file. The command already works fine, it's the Makefile that I'm having trouble with. Here's what I came up with:

```
all: $(OBJECTS)
OBJECTS := $(patsubst %.x,%.html,$(wildcard *.x)) 
%.html: %.x
    generate $< > $@
```

The OBJECTS variable is meant to contain all html files I need to generate. Invoking `make` states `nothing to be done for 'all'`, and there are no HTML files already in the directory.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out `make` is sensitive to the order of your variable definitions. The Makefile works when the first two lines are switched!