# Two step compilation procedure with gnu make

Tags: gnu-make

I have a bunch of files (`*.txt`) that I use a python script to analyze and generate code (`*.cpp`) from. Once code generation is complete, I want the generated code to be compiled into object files (`*.o`).

I want to use gnu-make to set this up. My problem is that I can't figure out a working Makefile syntax to accomplish this.

Here are some additional details that makes this harder:

Since I don't know how many *.txt-files exists in the first place, I want to discover them using a `shell find` command.

`files := $(shell find $(TXT_FILE_DIR) -type f -name '*.txt')`

However, I still want gnu-make's fine dependency features to work here. That is, if any of the txt-files change, I want `make` to automatically discover these and only these changes, and generate new `.cpp` files for them and recompile them into `.o` files.

I am looking for a solution where `make` can run in parallel (and respect the -j flag) and call the python script that translates the `*.txt` files into `*.cpp` files.

My OS is Linux.

[new information]

Thank you Grexis, for your answer! However, because I have a somewhat odd mapping between src and dst-paths, I am actually looking for a different solution.

Here is an example of "the oddity" when translating my src and dst-paths:

`$(TXT_DIR)/a/XXX.*XXX/b/c/file1.txt -> $(CPP_DIR)/a/YYY/b/c/file1.cpp
$(TXT_DIR)/a/XXX.*XXX/b/c/file2.txt -> $(CPP_DIR)/a/YYY/b/c/file2.cpp
$(TXT_DIR)/b/XXX.*XXX/c/d/file3.txt -> $(CPP_DIR)/b/YYY/c/d/file3.cpp`

Notice here that the path is manipulated twice. Hence, both:

1. `$(TXT_DIR)` is replaced with `$(CPP_DIR)` and
2. The regular expression `XXX.*XXX` is replaced with the fixed string `YYY`

However, due to that its hard to do a multiple string replacement in gnu-make, e.g., gnu-make only supports a single % (stem) string replacement at a time, I think I have to use a more advanced gnu-make syntax. Because of this, I am looking for a way to define a "distinct recipe for each `.txt` -> `.cpp` pair". I have tried the following:

`cleanPath = $(shell echo $(1) | sed s/XXX.*XXX/YYY/g)
txt2cpp = $(subst $(TXT_DIR),$(CPP_DIR),$(patsubst %.txt,%.cpp,$(call cleanPath,$(1))))
txt2obj = $(subst $(TXT_DIR),$(OBJ_DIR),$(patsubst %.txt,%.o,$(call cleanPath,$(1))))
define analyse =
$(2): $(1)
    python.py $(2) $(3)
endef
txt_files := $(shell find $(TXT_DIR) -type f -name '*.txt')
cpps := $(foreach file,$(txt_files),$(eval $(call analyse,$(file),$(call txt2cpp,$(file)),$(call txt2obj,$(file)))))
all: $(cpps)`

However, it seems my `python.py` script is never called. Why is that?

If I enclose the calling to the `python.py` in a `shell`-command, e.g.,`$(shell python.py $(2) $(3))`, the `python.py` script is actually called. However, using a `shell`-command makes parallelism impossible. Unfortunately, not being able to execute the `python.py` script in parallel is not an option for me.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit unclear if the each text file creates exactly one C++ source with a matching name (i.e. 'foo.txt' gets processed into 'foo.cpp' and then 'foo.o').

Assuming that it is a direct relation, the feature you are looking for is called [Pattern Rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Rules.html).

```
TXT_FILES := $(wildcard $(TXT_FILE_DIR)/*.txt)
OBJ_FILES := $(patsubst $(TXT_FILE_DIR)/%.txt,$(OUT_DIR)/%.o,$(TXT_FILES))

main: $(OBJ_FILES)
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^

$(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp: $(TXT_FILE_DIR)/%.txt
    $(PYTHON) process.py $<

$(OUT_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp
    $(CXX) -c $(CPPFLAGS) -o $@ $<
```

Breaking down the snippet above. `$(TXT_FILES)` is set to every `*.txt` file in `$(TXT_FILE_DIR)` with the wildcard operation in make. `$(OBJ_FILES)` uses pattern substitution with all the values in `$(TXT_FILES)`. Every obj file is then added as a dependency to the `main` executable.

As explained in the Pattern Rules link documentation linked above, every `.o` file needs the associated `.cpp` file in `$(SRC_DIR)` (The automatic variables `$@`, `$^`, and `$<` are also documented in the link provided). In turn, every `.cpp` file requires a `.txt` with the same name.

You'll probably have to tweak the exact invocation of your python script though. If a specific output file needs to be specified, the `$@` automatic variable should be used.

The section at the top for detecting all the source files was derived from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2908351).

Comment: I like this answer, but I think it would be improved by changing the patter rules into _static pattern rules_. Pretty easy in this case: `${OBJ_FILES}: ${OUT_DIR}/%.o: ${SRC_DIR}/%.cpp`